# locally univalent but not univalent

Tags: complex-analysis

Find complex function $f$ from open unit disk $\{z:|z|<1\}$ to itself satisfying $f'(z)$ is not $0$ for all $z$ but $f$ is univalent function, and then how to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is a "not" missing in your question. (Compare the title.)

Take $f(z) = ce^{az}$ where $|a|$ is large enough to keep $f$ from being injective and $|c|$ small enough to ensure that $f$ maps into the unit disc.

If you want surjectivity, you need to work harder.